# Why my functional component in reactjs mapping an empty array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, render

im sorry everyone to bug you..im new with reactjs and i really dont know why everytime i click "X" button in my functional component adding new empty line inside my map() my expectation is when i click "X" button its only log me something in my console. is anyone here can help explain what is happening and how to solve this? below here i post my code. please advise, thank you so much.

```
import './App.css';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import uniqid from 'uniqid';

function App() {
const [heldItems, setHeldItems] = useState({
    salesno: '',
    plu: '',
    price: 0,
    dateandtime: '',
});

const [salesItemsTemp, setSalesItemsTemp] = useState([]);

const handlerOnChange = (e) => {
    let heldItemsTemp = { ...heldItems };
    heldItemsTemp.salesno = uniqid();
    heldItemsTemp[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
    heldItemsTemp.dateandtime = new Date().toLocaleString();
    console.log(heldItemsTemp);
    setHeldItems(heldItemsTemp);
};

const handlerOnSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setSalesItemsTemp([...salesItemsTemp, { heldItems }]);
    setHeldItems({
        salesno: '',
        plu: '',
        price: 0,
        dateandtime: '',
    });
};

const handlerRemove = () => {
    console.log('its from handlerRemove !');
};

useEffect(
    () => console.log('helditems', heldItems),
    [heldItems],
);

return (
    <>
        <form onSubmit={handlerOnSubmit} autoComplete="off">
            <h1>POS</h1>
            <input
                type="text"
                placeholder="Input item name"
                name="plu"
                onChange={handlerOnChange}
                value={heldItems.plu}
            />
            PLU
            <input
                type="number"
                placeholder="Input item price"
                name="price"
                onChange={handlerOnChange}
                value={heldItems.price}
            />
            Price
            <button type="submit">add item</button>
            <div>
                <ul>
                    {salesItemsTemp.map((sales) => {
                        console.log('mapping sales', sales);
                        const { salesno, plu, price, dateandtime } =
                            sales.heldItems;
                        return (
                            <li key={salesno}>
                                <p>salesno : {salesno}</p>
                                <p>plu : {plu}</p>
                                <p>price : {price}</p>
                                <p>dateandtime : {dateandtime}</p>
                                <button onClick={handlerRemove}>X</button>
                            </li>
                        );
                    })}
                </ul>
            </div>
        </form>
    </>
);
```

}

export default App;

Comment: Quick Q: does it happen even if you change the "button" to a "span"?

Comment: What do you mean with "adding empty lines inside your map"?

Comment: Hey, in your method `handlerRemove` you are `console.log`ing something. There is no logic there

Comment: What @JoelPeltonen is hinting at is that maybe your `<button>` reloads your page (because you forgot to set it to `type="button"`). But even without that not much would happen because your `handlerRemove` doesn't remove anything.

Comment: @CherryDT  handlerOnSubmit  is calling prevetDefault, so that shouldn't cause a page refresh, but it will still call the handler, so your right he should be setting `type="button"` to stop that as the default for button is submit (daft as it sounds).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're submitting your form when you're pressing the X button here:

`<form onSubmit={handlerOnSubmit} autoComplete="off">`

which is running the following line in your `handlerOnSubmit` function, adding an empty entry to your items.

`setSalesItemsTemp([...salesItemsTemp, { heldItems }]);`

Use `type="button"` on your X button to prevent the form submitting. Alternatively, move the submit handler to an onClick event on the submit button, rather than on the form.

Comment: `type="button"` is the better option, otherwise you loose the default `enter` key option.

Comment: Re-worded my answer to prefer that method. Thanks @Keith.

Comment: omg.... i missed that... and its work like magic.. thank you so much for your advise.. i will work harder..